# How to convert SMART-PLS structural coefficients from standardized (correlation) to unstandardized?

Tags: regression, structural-equation-modeling, partial-least-squares

I need use smartPLS but i also have prediction purpose (coefficients should also act like b-coefficients of regression). How to do this in smartPLS, since all coefficients are standardized?

Answer (score 1):

In SmartPLS, you can [get unstandardized path coefficient](https://forum.smartpls.com/viewtopic.php?t=29365)s in the IPMA (importance-performance map analysis) analysis. Follow these steps to run IPMA in SmartPLS (v.3):

**First**, select IMPA from the 'Calculation' menu

[image]

**Second**, select a dependent variable as the target (SAT in this example)

[image]

**Third**, open the report and click 'Latent Variables' to see the scores

[image]

**Fourth**, by default, you will see standardized scores. Click on 'Unstandardized'

[image]

**Fifth**, you will find what you are looking for here. In this example, the survey response scale was a 1-7 Likert. Therefore, the unstandardized scores are in the range of 1-7.

[image]

**More about IMPA analysis in SmartPLS:**

- Introductory information about [IMPA analysis is available on the SmartPLS website](https://www.smartpls.com/documentation/algorithms-and-techniques/ipma/).
- This article offers some details on [how to report IMPA analysis](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jretai.2022.03.003); see Web Appendix W9 for a detailed discussion. This is an open-access article.